# Can one decompose any ring into a (possibly infinite) product of indecomposable rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring. Do there exist indecomposable rings $R_i$, $i\in I$, such that $R={\prod}_{i\in I} R_i$?

Comment: When you say indecomposable ring, you mean connected ring yes?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I think it's pretty clear what an indecomposable ring is (commutative or not), and there is no need to replace it by a restrictive definition.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R\subset\mathbb Z_2^{\mathbb N}$ be the set of sequences with elements in $\mathbb Z_2$ which are constant from a rank on. Then $R$ is a [boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring). If $R\simeq\prod_{i\in I}R_i$ with $R_i$ indecomposable, then $R_i$ is isomorphic to a subring of $R$, hence $R_i$ is boolean. Moreover, since $R_i$ is indecomposable we must have $R_i\simeq\mathbb Z_2$. This shows that $R\simeq\mathbb Z_2^{I}$, but for cardinality reasons this is false.

Comment: The cardinality reason being that the set of eventually constant $\mathbb{Z}_2$-valued sequences is countable, while $\mathbb{Z}_2^I$ is either finite (if $I$ is finite) or uncountable (if $I$ is infinite). Right?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese You are right.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Nice example.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Try $R$ the ring of  continuous functions from $C= \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.